Make two disks just touch
I have two disks, that I want to make touching each other. One disk is fixed, the other can shift along the x axis. The shift should be determined to make the disks intersecting in one point (or have the distance Zero).
(*Disk one shiftable*)    
rB[m_] := Region[Disk[{m, 0}, 0.5]];
(*fixed disk two*)
r1 = Region@Disk[{0, 0.5/2 + 0.15}, 0.15];
touch = NMinimize[{RegionDistance[rB[v], r1]], -0.6 < 
    v < -0.5}, {v}]

I thought it is an easy task, as v is linearly going to Zero. However, NMinimize does fail here completely. It does not even try to start. RegionDistance give a value in this definition. However, it always gives Zero if the circles intersect. Still the NMinimize function gives a value v in return that would yield a none Zero distance.
Any suggestions how to solve the issue?

As you have figured it out yourself, when the two regions overlap, RegionDistance gives zero. Therefore, you have to include another constraint of the two regions being disjoint. You can do this, for example, using RegionIntersection:
touch = NMinimize[{RegionDistance[rB[v], r1], -0.6 < v < -0.5 && 
    Area@RegionIntersection[rB[v], r1] == 0}, {v}]
(* {0., {v -> -0.512348}} *)

RegionPlot[{r1, rB[v] /. Last@touch}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]


Alternatively, you can use synthetic geometry functionalities, introduced in version 14, to find the exact values:
hypothesis = GeometricAssertion[{Circle[{m, 0}, 1/2], 
    Circle[{0, 1/4 + 15/100}, 15/100]}, "PairwiseTangent"];
scene = GeometricScene[{{}, {m}}, {hypothesis}];

GeometricSolveValues[scene, m]
(* {-(Sqrt[(21/5)]/4), Sqrt[21/5]/4} *)


RegionDisjoint get the inequalitie which the two disks disjoint.
rB[m_] := Disk[{m, 0}, 0.5];
r1 = Disk[{0, 0.5/2 + 0.15}, 0.15];
condition = RegionDisjoint[rB[m], r1] // Rationalize
sol = Reduce[condition, m]


4/25 + m^2 > 169/400


m < -(Sqrt[(21/5)]/4) || m > Sqrt[21/5]/4


We can also test another regions such as Ellipsoid or DiskSegment etc and move along another line such as{m,2m}.

Clear["Global`*"];
ellip[m_] := Disk[{m, 2  m}, {0.5, .3}];
r1 = DiskSegment[{0, 0}, {3, 2}, {-Pi/4, 3  Pi/4}];
condition = RegionDisjoint[ellip[m], r1] // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
sol = Solve[CylindricalDecomposition[condition, m, "Boundary"], m]
Graphics[{Red, r1, Blue, ellip[m] /. sol}]


{{m -> -(21338875/126888487)}, {m -> 121172719/110902961}}


